Will the browser send a new request to the server, so the Server Components re-render, if cookies are set in a Client Component via a Server Action?
In Next.js 15, using React 19, will the browser automatically send a new request to the server, so the Server Components re-render, after cookies are set in a Client Component via a Server Action?
Or is it necessary to manually call router.refresh() from the Client Component?
Is the behavior documented anywhere?
I am getting mixed results in testing and not sure what is going on under the hood.

Try to call router.refresh() after setting cookies via a server action.
Look at the docs
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#routerrefresh
In there it says that the refresh option of the useRouter hook can be used to manually refresh a route. This completely clears the Router Cache, and makes a new request to the server for the current route. refresh does not affect the Data or Full Route Cache.
The rendered result will be reconciled on the client while preserving React state and browser state.

Thank you, Lucas. Great to see someone on here who has actually read up on the different cache types. Given your reply, I assume your view is also that the SC does not automatically rerender when a SA sets cookies. In other words, it is always necessary to manually call router.refresh() in the CC, after the call to the SA, if the SC(s) in the route uses cookies and the new value is needed. Is that your understanding as well? Thanks again!

You're welcome ! Yes, that's correct. Next.js won't automatically pre-render the server component (SC) when cookies are set via s server action (SA). I think in those cases, it would be the best idea to manually call router.refresh() in the client component (CC) after the SA ensures the updated cookie value is reflected in the SC.

Hello again Lucas. I just got the following reply from a contributor to the Next.js repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/70054#discussioncomment-10852582. It seems conflicting with your findings above (which correspond to my own understanding). Specifically, the team says: Also, if cookies are mutated inside an Action, it's expected to re-render the app because there could be data that depends on cookies.. I know it says expected, but the whole thread, and icyjoseph's reply, seem to indicate that SC does indeed automatically re-render when cookies are set in SA.

I think I discovered something relevant here. In the Docs section on invalidating the Router Cache, it is stated that the Router Cache is invalidated when cookies are set/deleted in a SA. Meaning, next time any navigation is done within the app, a new request is sent to the server to get the new RSC payload: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#invalidation-1. So, even though setting cookies invalidates the cache, it does not immediately send a new request to the server. However, router.refresh() both invalidates the Router Cache and immediately sends a new req.
